# Маршрутизация между двумя сетями в Ubuntu 12.04 используя iptables

Tags: iptables, ubuntu, маршрутизация, linux

Три компа, все с ubuntu 12.04. Первый ПК используется как сервер обновлений и ПО для остальных. Сервер обновлений работает через http. Нужно чтобы vpnshluze (т.е. третий ПК) мог получать обновления с первого ПК. Осваиваю программу iproute но пока всё очень тяжко. В идеале третий комп должен видеть первый исключительно через поднятый VPN. VPN адрес для третьего ПК статичен 192.169.2.201. P.S. поднять VPN на третьем компе пока не удалось, но в винде коннект работает и ip присваивается, к тому же глючит настройка сети через ГУИ, через терминал пока ничего не менял. Но настройка в процессе.На всех интерфейсах маска одна: 255.255.255.0![alt text][1]Настройка VPN на втором ПК:**файл /etc/pptpd.conf:**        option /etc/ppp/pptpd-options    logwtmp     bcrelay eth1    localip 192.169.2.1    remoteip 192.169.2.200-250    **файл /etc/ppp/pptpd-options:**    name pptpd    refuse-pap    refuse-chap    refuse-mschap    require-mschap-v2    require-mppe-128    proxyarp    nodefaultroute    lock    nobsdcomp    refuse-pap    refuse-chap    refuse-mschap    require-mschap-v2    require-mppe-128    **файл /etc/ppp/chap-secrets:**    office1 * 123456 192.169.2.201  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PXML.png

Comment: vpn с 3 компа до какого , укажите .

Comment: vpn сервер на втором до клиента на третьем

Comment: На схеме нету  интерфейсов  vpn  и ip  адресов  vpn. Добавьте.

Comment: изменил описание. повторюсь - vpn сервера 192.169.2.1 клиента 192.169.2.201 маска везде одна 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотрите алгоритм следующий

1. Вкл forwardind  на второй машине (то что /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foraward)
2. Разрешить трафик на пакетном фильтре так же на второй машине (iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT), можно и лучше конечно указать конкретно что разрешить.
3. На 3 машине прописать маршрут к сети назначения (первый комп), ip r a 192.169.2.201 via  192.169.2.1
4. Profit ?!

Comment: завтра проверю. Если можно всё тоже самое, только командами в терминале.

Comment: Да , только уже не тут и не за бесплатно. Команда одна - разберись и сделай.

Comment: Для более простого общения с iptables могу порекомендовать Shorewall. С его помощью правила iptables строить гораздо проще.

Comment: @Justicet и чем же с shorewall проще ? она убога. Правила iptables (если их использовать как ip**tables**) понятны сами по себе, а эта недоабстракция только все усложняет и отрывает половину нужного функционала. просто покажите мне конфиг shorewall который я не смогу сделать красиво в iptables,iproute,tc (может пару строчек на bash еще напишу, чтобы сгенерить правила в цикле)

Comment: @eicto : с Shorewall тем проще, что синтаксис правил более простой. А если уж все-таки требуется - то есть и возможность тонкой настройки.

Comment: сделал так:на PC 192.169.3.1sudo ip route add 192.169.1.2 via 192.169.2.1на PC 192.169.1.2sudo ip route add 192.169.2.10 via 192.169.1.1на PC 192.169.(1-2).1форвардинг http://www.ithowto.ru/75-kak-vklyuchit-ip-forwarding-v-linux.htmlсамо собой всё работает только до перезагрузки (форвардинг работает и после перезагрузки). Мне не понятно, для чего Вы написали команду iptables? И как сделать чтобы всё работало и после перезагрузки?мне нужно передавать данные на 80 порту и 22

Comment: @shaman888  в винде, в команде route имеется ключ добавления правила с сохранением и после перезагрузки.  Вполне возможно, что и в ip route есть нечто подобное - посмотрите ключи команды.